# Write from output stream to output stream

Tags: java, outputstream

I have an outputstream, to which the client A is writing , I need to forward it  in byte chuncks to client B.

I'd like to connect the output stream of client A with the output stream of client B. Is that possible? What are ways to do that?
I don't need to fork/clone I rather need to take some of the data from stream A and move it to stream B(i.e the data don't stay in stream A)

Note:A and B are processes and outputstream of client A can't be directly supplied to client B.
Constraint:Limited memory

Comment: Well... Client B has an input stream. Which, I think, is what you are mistaking for Client A's output stream

Comment: @user2651804 no both of them output

Comment: Provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to get quick answer

Comment: What do you mean by client A and B.  Are they separate threads, processes or just objects in your program?

Comment: A and B are processes

Comment: Sounds like the tee command on Linux, which forks one output to two outputs. A search found a java Tee: https://github.com/apache/tomee/blob/master/container/openejb-core/src/main/java/org/apache/openejb/util/Tee.java

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/Pipe.html?

Comment: I don't need to fork/clone I rather need to take some ot the data from stream A and move it to stream B(i.e the data don't stay in stream A)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this approach; it transfers bytes ("Hello world") written to 'out' to 'out2' without use of an InputStream:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class OutputStreamEx {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String content = "Hello world";
    byte[] bytes = content.getBytes();
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        ByteArrayOutputStream out2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out.writeTo(out2);
        System.out.println(out2.toString());
     } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
     }
  }
 }
```